# NSPredicate with IN NSNumbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nsnumber

I have set up an NSPredicate to check if the object `category_id` is `IN` in an NSArray of numbers.

The code:

```
 ///This is working

NSArray *arr2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@[@3,@2,@3],nil];

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category_id IN %@", arr2]

//This is not working

NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:category_array]; //Array with NSNumbers

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category_id IN %@", arr]
```

This was working fine but after I changed my `category_array` to contains NSNumber the predicate stopped working. How I use NSPredicate for NSNumber?

Update:
Arrays:

[image]

Entity for `Category`:

[image]

Comment: how does new category array look like ? its also NSNumber ( the first line of the code )

Comment: I update the answer how it looks in the debugger.

Comment: How are you using this predicate?  What is `category_id`?  Is it the property of some object?

Comment: Yes. I update the answer

Comment: Why are you creating an array with the objects on an array that you just created?! `@[]` is EXACTLY the same as `[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:]` so you are creating an array and use it to create an array with its contents. What for?

Comment: Also, can you please ensure you code is right? It seems you have written it in the question insert of c&p. You are searching an array of arrays. But if you'd do so in you'r real code, I think it would never work.

Comment: OK I updated the answer. The `arr2` is just for testing. I need to use `arr`

Answer (score 0):

You are making minor but blatant mistake here. You are adding an array `@[@1,@2,@4]` as an object in the array `category_array`.

Try:

```
NSArray *category_array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:@[@1,@2,@4]];
```

or simply

```
NSArray *category_array = @[@1,@2,@4];
```

Comment: Sorry that was typo. Using that way is working fine. the problem is when I am adding NSNumber with `[array addObject:num]`

Comment: @BlackM - Also, your `category_id` is String and not a Number. That could be an issue.

Comment: Yes I know I just add it as String for simplicity. Anyway it was working with the first approach. I will try changing that and let you know

Comment: Please add that working code as well to the question.

Comment: The first block of code does not make any sense at all. Why should he allocate an array from an array? The `@[]` shortcut was created to replace the whole alloc-init-stuff. This just creates unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a little mistake

try out this code

```
NSArray *category_array = @[@1,@2,@4];
```

Comment: My array is dynamically built using NSNumber so I cant do that